# Horas em timestamp

Tags: script, timestamp, perl

Fala ai galera, tudo beleza?

É possível eu saber quanto é duas horas na conversão `timestamp`?

Nessa linha eu converto o horário atual em `timestamp`.

`$hours_2 = str2time(localtime());`

Mas preciso saber como retirar duas horas do resultado, ficando `$hours_2` - duas horas... Não estou conseguindo de nenhum jeito.

Answer (score 1):

A função do Perl `localtime` aceita um parâmetro `time` que é um Unix Epoch na unidade de segundos. Em Perl

```
localtime(time())
```

é a mesma coisa que

```
localtime()
```

Sabendo disso, para obter o resultado menos duas horas, basta remover 2 * 60 * 60 = 7200 segundos do parâmetro

```
my $hours_2 = localtime(time() - 7200);
```